How to make variants of an existing command without copying the code of the command?
I'm making some new commands such as a version of \prod but with a \Psi instead of the \Pi, but it's very complicated, because of the superscript and subscript that are respectivly directly on the top and directly on the bottom, and also the changes between \displaystyle, \textstyle, \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle, and some other things.
So, I was thinking about a way to copy the \prod command, but with replacing the ∏ by \Psi. Does this exist? And if yes, how to use it?
It would be nice if the code works also with KaTeX.

@StevenB.Segletes , not really, that I want is to create a thing like \prod but with a \Psi instead of the ∏.

I removed the reference to KaTeX in the title and at the beginning of the question, that would make the question off-topic for the site.

@egreg Thanks.­

Scaling like \prod might not be the real solution, but almost.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Psiop}{}{%
  \DOTSB\mathop{%
    \vphantom{\prod}\mathpalette\Psiop@\relax
  }\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\Psiop@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{\raisebox{\depth}{$#1\prod$}}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\resizebox{!}{%
    \Psiop@adjust{#1}\ht\z@}{$\m@th#1\Psi$%
  }}}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\Psiop@adjust}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 0.88\else % 1 for newtx,newpx; 1.04 for kpfonts
  \ifx#1\textstyle 1\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1\else
  1\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\prod_{i=1}^{n} \Psiop_{i=1}^n
\]
\begin{center}
$\prod\Psiop\scriptstyle\prod\Psiop\scriptscriptstyle\prod\Psiop$
\end{center}

\end{document}

The code contains vertical adjustments for the scaling factor. With visual experiments it seems that only displaystyle needs adjustments, but I left also factors for the other styles, just in case. I found that

0.88 is good for Computer Modern or Latin Modern (in the latter case remember to load fixcmex)
1 is good for NewTX or NewPX
1.04 is good for KpFonts

Other fonts might need other factors.
Picture with Computer Modern

With KaTeX you could try
\mathop{\Psi}\limits_{n=1}^{2}

but the result is quite poor.

Does it work with KaTeX?

@KarlLÉOGNANY Of course not. KaTeX is a JavaScript program and is not TeX. Only a small part of LaTeX is implemented, but essentially nothing related to real typography (which is the case here).

I know that KaTeX isn't TeX, but the big problem is that it's for an online real-time math LaTeX renderer using KaTeX.

@KarlLÉOGNANY Ask the KaTeX people. This site doesn't deal with it.

@KarlLÉOGNANY The best approximation I can offer with KaTeX is \mathop{\Huge\Psi}\limits_{n=1}^{10}, but it's obviously a kludge.

The code for KaTeX work, thanks. It's better using \huge instead of \Huge.

I've just a thing to ask you: How to make it work with \psiop_{n=1}^{10} being \mathop{\huge\Psi}\limits_{n=1}^{10}?

@KarlLÉOGNANY It can’t work in LaTeX, if that’s what you’re asking. If it’s specific for KaTeX, ask in their site.

­Thanks for the clarifying.

This takes on the vertical footprint of \prod, but using a \Psi, instead.  Script styles are recognized and obeyed. Please help me understand what it is you need, if this is not it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\Psi}{\prod}}
\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)

\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))_{
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) _
{\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))}}
\]
\end{document} 



Thanks, it's this. That I was wanting is to have a \Psi instead of the ∏ of the \prod.

Do you have the same thing but for KaTeX?

@KarlLÉOGNANY I don't know anything about KaTeX, with which to give an answer to your comment.

Oh. It's because I'm using an online real-time LaTeX renderer that use KaTeX. I tried with an other that use MathJax, and it work, but it's for my own online real-time LaTeX renderer that use KaTeX.
